# The remote will not open any doors until I have opened drivers door with key

Tags: key

From outside, all doors will lock except drivers side door lock, using the remote.  I can lock drivers side with key only.
Then I cannot unlock any of the doors without using the key - or once I open drivers side lock with key, then the remote will open any of the other doors.

(tried with two remotes so problem not with remote)

Comment: What is the make/year/model of the vehicle?

Comment: Hard to say much without knowing the year and model.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the driver door lock motor/solenoid is bad. There is probably an interlock that won't unlock the rest of the doors until the driver's door unlocks.

Check the signal to the door, if it gets a signal when the command is sent then the motor is bad.